# Remotely Debugging Opera for Android

Tags: android, debugging, opera

I am attempting to remotely debug Opera for Android. I have installed the Android SDK, have remote debugging checked on the phone, chrome on my pc, Android 4.3, and have successfully been able to remotely debug in Chrome and Firefox. I am following the instructions for [Remotely Debugging Opera for Android](https://dev.opera.com/articles/remotely-debugging-opera-for-android/) and it says:

> Connect desktop to device
>
> Start Opera for Android, and enable debugging by entering opera:debug
>   in your address bar and checking the “enable” checkbox in the
>   resulting page, as seen below.

When I type the address, I don't get a resulting checkbox but only the message "This webpage is not available The webpage at chrome://debug/ might be temporarily down ...etc..." and the address bar shows:  `opera://debug/`

I've got the latest version of Opera (35). Any ideas?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Klemens I am now on Opera 43 and Android Studio 3 but I still can not enter debug mode. I will post to their forum, but a past post with the same issue did not receive any help.